# Can fields be nested in Solr?

Tags: solr

I need to have fields nested inside of fields, does solr provide that ability ?

For example : I need to have a multivalued field called Products, and each Product needs to in-turn have a multivalued field Properties. I need there to be nesting, so that in case, I search for a property, it only returns the corresponding product info and not all products

Currently, I find that if I have 10 products which each have 10 properties in each doc, upon searching for a property, all the products in that doc(which holds that property) would be returned. And now again I'd have to manually sort out which product had that property, by comparing the array indices. So if property 53 is returned, it would be the 6th product. Thisgets worse when not all products have an equal number of properties.

Is there no easier way ?
Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, recent Solr supports nested document. Though, there are some tradeoffs. Mostly, that you had to index and delete the whole parent+children block together. But it should not be a problem for your case.

After that, you can search them in a couple of different ways using [BlockJoins](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is useful in your situation but this is what I am doing in my `data-config.xml`

```
<document>
<entity name="paper" query="SELECT * FROM papers">
    <field column="title" name="title"/>
    <field column="title" name="title_unstem"/>
    <field column="year" name="publish_date"/>
    <entity name="person" query="SELECT * FROM papers_people PA, people A WHERE PA.person_id = A.id AND PA.paper_id='${paper.id}'">
        <field column="id" name="author_id"/>
        <field column="first_name" name="first_name"/>
        <field column="last_name" name="last_name"/>
        <field column="full_name" name="author"/>
     </entity>
     <entity name="volume" query="SELECT * FROM volumes WHERE id='${paper.volume_id}'">
         <field column="id" name="volume_id"/>
         <field column="title" name="volume_title"/>
         <field column="anthology_id" name="volume_anthology"/>
     </entity>
</entity>
</document>
```

Basically as you can see my Paper has many Authors and belongs to a Volume. I am doing this on Ruby on Rails with the Blacklight gem so if you have any questions just ask me.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I can't use DIH. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your key requirements and you haven't invested much in solr, then, I suggest you look at elasticsearch. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html

Otherwise, blockjoin is the only out of the box way to do it in solr and it looks more like a hack.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I've gone too far to now ditch solr, I'll stick with it and try the blockjoin.